# Metaprogramming inheritance limitiations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, metaprogramming, instantiation

I am using template metaprogramming in c++ to generate a hierarchy of classes from using a typelist like so:

```
//! Basic typelist class
template<class H, class T>
class Typelist
{
public:
    typedef H Head;
    typedef T Tail;
};

//! Terminating type
class NullType {};

//! Forward declaration
template<class Types>
class Recur;

//! Specialisation to terminate the recursion
template<>
class Recur<NullType>
{
};

//! General recursive class 
template<class Types>
class Recur: public Recur<typename Types::Tail>
{
};

// Dummy classes 
class Type1{};
class Type2{};
class Type3{};
int main()
{
    // Defines the typelist
    typedef Typelist<Type1,Typelist<Type2,Typelist<Type3,NullType>>> Types;

    // Instantiate the recursion
    Recur<Types> recur;
    return 1;
}
```

This would produce a class hierarchy like so:

`Recur<Typelist<Type2,Typelist<Type3,NullType>>>` which derives from:
`Recur<Typelist<Type3,NullType>>` which derives from:

```
Recur<NullType> (base class)
```

**Question: Are there any Visual Studio 2010 compiler limits to the depth of class derivation using this recursive technique? In other words if my typelist contained N types would the code above compile and construct N classes even if N equals say 100,000?**

Comment: It is best to not rely on such implementation specific details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annex B of the [Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) specifies only a minimum level of direct and indirect base classes and nested template instantiations, and it's a quality of implementation issue whether a specific compiler goes beyond that. Consult your specific compilers own documentation for the precies numbers. Below follow the minimum quantities required by the Standard.

**Annex B (informative)
Implementation quantities [implimits]**

> 1 Because computers are ﬁnite, C++ implementations are inevitably
> limited in the size of the programs they can successfully process.
> Every implementation shall document those limitations where known.
> This documentation may cite ﬁxed limits where they exist, say how to
> compute variable limits as a function of available resources, or say
> that ﬁxed limits do not exist or are unknown.
>
> 2 The limits may constrain quantities that include those described
> below or others. The bracketed number following each quantity is
> recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these
> quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance.
>
> — Direct and indirect base classes [16 384].
>
> — Direct base classes for a single class [1 024].
>
> — Recursively nested template instantiations, including substitution
> during template argument deduction (14.8.2) [1 024].